# Update action button in a dataframe

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs

In my data frame, I have an actionbutton and I would like it to change the colour, label, but also increment a value "yes" in my database that I can download after.

```
shinyInput <- function(FUN, len, id, ...) {
    inputs <- character(len)
    for (i in seq_len(len)) {
      inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), ...))
    }
    inputs
    }

    df <- reactiveValues(data = data.frame(
    validation = shinyInput(actionButton, 1, id = "button_",
                            label = "Check",
                            style = "color: white; background-color: #222D32",
                            onclick = 'Shiny.onInputChange(\"select_button\", this.id)')
  ))
```

And for the update button

```
observeEvent(input$select_button, {
    selectedRow <- as.character("yes")
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "f_check", choices = c("All", selectedRow))
    updateActionButton(session, inputId = "button_", label = "Yes")
  })
```

Here is the entire code.

```
library(DT)
library(readODS)
library(dplyr)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

base <- read_ods("base.ods")

createLink <- function(val) {
  sprintf('<a href= "%s" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary">Fiches données</a>',val)
}

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title ="MobiDiag"),

  dashboardSidebar(

    tags$head(tags$style(HTML('.logo {
                                background-color: #8eb06a !important;
                                }
                                .navbar {
                                background-color: #a7cd7f !important;
                                }'
    ))),

    h4(strong("Critères de sélection"), align="center"),

    prettyCheckboxGroup("territoire", "Territoire",
                        thick = TRUE,
                        shape = "curve",
                        animation = "pulse",
                        choices = c("Communes centrales" = "Communes.centrales", "Communes pôles urbain" = "Communes.poles.urbain", "Communes secondaires" = "Communes.secondaires", "Communes rurales" = "Communes.rurales", "Ensemble territoire" = "Ensemble.territoire", "Périmètre élargit" = "Perimetre.elargit")),
    prettyCheckboxGroup("doc", "Documents de planification existants",
                        thick = TRUE,
                        shape = "curve",
                        animation = "pulse",
                        choices = c("Volet mobilité SCOT" = "Volet.mobilite.SCOT", "PDU obligatoire" = "PDU.obligatoire", "PGD volontaire" = "PGD.volontaire", "PLUI","Plan de mobilité rurale" = "Plan.mobilite.rurale", "PCAET", "PLUIHD")),

    actionButton("submit", ("Extraction")),

  ),

  dashboardBody(
    fluidPage(

      useShinyjs(),
      inlineCSS(list(.green = "background: #A7CD7F")),
      actionButton(inputId = "button_", label = "test"),

      mainPanel(width = 12,
                tabsetPanel(

                  tabPanel("Extraction",
                           fluidRow(
                             br(),

                             column(width=2,
                                    selectInput("f_st",
                                                "Sous-thèmes :",
                                                "")
                             ),
                             column(width=2,
                                    selectInput("f_don",
                                                "Données :",
                                                "")
                             ),
                             column(width=2,
                                    selectInput("f_check",
                                                "Validation :",
                                                "")
                             ),
                             column(width=2,
                                    selectInput("f_doc",
                                                "Documents de planification :",
                                                "")
                             ),
                             column(width=12, DT::dataTableOutput("Synthese"))

                           )
                  ),

                  tabPanel("Statistiques",
                           fluidRow(
                             br(),
                             valueBoxOutput("mdbox", width = 2),
                             valueBoxOutput("tcbox", width = 2),
                             valueBoxOutput("atcbox", width = 2),
                             valueBoxOutput("crbox", width = 2),
                             valueBoxOutput("marchbox", width = 2),
                             valueBoxOutput("stabox", width = 2),
                             valueBoxOutput("peibox", width = 2),
                             valueBoxOutput("mmbox", width = 2),
                             valueBoxOutput("terbox", width = 2)
                           )
                  ),

                  tabPanel("Ajout de données",
                           fluidRow(
                             br(),
                             selectInput("sous.themes.insert","Sous-Thèmes :", c("", unique(as.character(base$sous.themes)))),
                             textInput("donnees.insert","Données :"),

                             actionButton("insert", ("Ajout"))
                           )
                  ),

                  tabPanel("Aide",
                           fluidRow(br(),
                                    "Documentation sur l'outil"
                           )
                  )
                )
      ))))

server = function(input, output, session) {

  output$mdbox <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      sum(FinalData()$sous.themes == "Mode doux"),
      "Modes doux",
      icon = icon("bicycle"),
      color = "olive"
    )
  })

  output$tcbox <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      sum(FinalData()$sous.themes == "Transports en commun"),
      "Transports en commun",
      icon = icon("bus"),
      color = "orange"
    )
  })

  output$atcbox <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      sum(FinalData()$sous.themes == "Autres transports collectifs"),
      "Autre transports collectifs",
      icon = icon("bus"),
      color = "maroon"
    )
  })

  output$crbox <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      sum(FinalData()$sous.themes == "Circulation routière"),
      "Circulation routière",
      icon = icon("car"),
      color = "red"
    )
  })

  output$marchbox <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      sum(FinalData()$sous.themes == "Marchandise"),
      "Marchandise",
      icon = icon("dolly-flatbed"),
      color = "yellow"
    )
  })

  output$stabox <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      sum(FinalData()$sous.themes == "Stationnement"),
      "Stationnement",
      icon = icon("parking"),
      color = "purple"
    )
  })

  output$peibox <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      sum(FinalData()$sous.themes == "Pôles d'échanges et intermodalité"),
      "Pôles d'échanges et intermodalité",
      icon = icon("arrows-alt"),
      color = "navy"
    )
  })

  output$mmbox <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      sum(FinalData()$sous.themes == "Management de la mobilité"),
      "Management de la mobilité",
      icon = icon("map-marked"),
      color = "blue"
    )
  })

  output$terbox <- renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      sum(FinalData()$sous.themes == "Caractéristiques du territoire"),
      "Caractéristiques du territoire",
      icon = icon("globe"),
      color = "light-blue"
    )
  })

  shinyInput <- function(FUN, len, id, ...) {
    inputs <- character(len)
    for (i in seq_len(len)) {
      inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), ...))
    }
    inputs
  }

  df <- reactiveValues(data = data.frame(
    validation = shinyInput(actionButton, 1,
                            id = "button_",
                            label = "Check",
                            onclick = 'Shiny.onInputChange(\"select_button\", this.id)',
                            stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
    lien_fiches = createLink(base$fiches.donnees)[1]
  ))

  create_rules <- reactive({
    paste(c(input$territoire, input$doc), "== 'Oui'",  collapse = " | ")
  })

  FinalData <- eventReactive(input$submit,{
    if(is.null(c(input$territoire, input$doc)))
      return()
    else (base %>% filter_(create_rules()))
  })

  fdt <- eventReactive(input$submit,{
    tmp_fdt <- cbind(FinalData()[1:2], df$data)
    colnames(tmp_fdt) <- c("Sous-thèmes", "Données", "Validation", "Fiches données")
    tmp_fdt
    })

  filter <- reactive({
    filtered_data <- fdt()
    if (input$f_st != "Tous" & input$f_don == "Tous"){
      filtered_data <- filtered_data[FinalData()$sous.themes == input$f_st,]
    }
    if (input$f_don != "Tous" & input$f_st == "Tous"){
      filtered_data <- filtered_data[FinalData()$donnees == input$f_don,]
    }
    if (input$f_st != "Tous" & input$f_don != "Tous"){
      filtered_data <- filtered_data[FinalData()$sous.themes == input$f_st & FinalData()$donnees == input$f_don,]
    }
    return(filtered_data)
  })

  output$Synthese <-  DT::renderDT(DT::datatable({

    filter()

  },

  escape = FALSE,
  selection = "none",
  extensions="Buttons",
  options = list(
    pageLength = 10,

    initComplete = JS(
      "function(settings, json) {",
      "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#1A242F', 'color': '#fff'});",
      "}"),

    dom="Bfrtip",
    buttons =  list(list(
      extend = "collection",
      filename = "Extraction",
      buttons = c("copy", "csv", "excel", "pdf"),
      text = "Télécharger la sélection")
    ),
    language = list(paginate = 
                      list('next'="suivant", 
                           'previous'="précédent"),
                    info = "Pages de _PAGE_ à _PAGES_",
                    search = "Rechercher",
                    infoFiltered = "(filtre des _MAX_ lignes)")
              )
  ))

  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "f_st", choices = c("Tous", FinalData()$sous.themes))
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "f_don", choices = c("Tous", FinalData()$donnees))
    updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "f_doc", choices = c("Tous", input$doc))
  })

  observeEvent(input$select_button, {
      addCssClass(id = "button_", class = "green")
      updateSelectInput(session, inputId = "f_check", choices = c("Tous", "Ok", "Check"))
  })

}

shinyApp(UI, server)
```

In the fluid page, I made a 'test' actionbutton in order to try addCssClass and it works but not with the actionbutton in the data frame.

Thanks

Comment: To update the color of an actionButton, i think the best (only ?) way is to change the CSS class with `shinyjs::removeCssClass()` and `addCssClass()` inside the `observeEvent()`

Comment: I try this ```addCssClass(id = "button_", class = "green")  ``` It works with a normal actionbutton, but not with the actionbutton in my dataframe.

Comment: Can you provide a reproductible example please

Comment: I add the entire code.

Comment: Your button has an inline style and a CSS property set in an inline style has priority over the same CSS property set in a class. That's why `addCssClass` does not have any effect, I think. To change the color you can do `runjs("$('#button_').css({'background-color': '#A7CD7F'})")`.

Comment: I remove the inline style and put runjs into the observeEvent, but the result is the same. The color of the test button change but not the button in the dataframe. Maybe the problem comes from the Shinyinput function ?

Comment: @Georom did you find any solution on that?